# ASP.NET route values does not blend in with the mapped routes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have this route mapped:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "SingleUser", // Route name
    "Users/{username}", // URL with parameters
    new {area="", controller = "Users", action = "SingleUser"}, // Parameter defaults
 );
```

Shouldn't this code:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Users", new {username = "someUser"});
```

redirect to this URL: `localhost/Users/someUser`?

It instead returns me to: `localhost/Users?username=someUser`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've defined a specialized route, then you should use `RedirectToRoute`.

```
return RedirectToRoute("SingleUser", new { username = "someUser" });
```

What's happening is that MVC is falling back to the default route ("{controller}/{action}").

Use `RedirectToAction` when you don't have a specialized route defined.

Same goes for generating links with `ActionLink` and `RouteLink`.

Comment: @Lol - nice. No badge though. :)